# Want to use something like an eval() or Function() to evaluate a string inside of a serverless project

Tags: javascript, eval, aws-serverless, serverless-webpack-plugin

I need to evaluate a string that I get in a function parameter. I've done it before using both eval() and Function(). But when I try the same thing with eval() inside of an AWS serverless project, I get a serverless webpack compilation error saying "eval can be harmful" and when I try Function(), I get an error "The Function constructor is eval".

The code is something like this:

```
function evaluate(x, op, y) {
    const expression = `x + op + y`;
    return eval(expression); // or return Function(`return ${expression}`)
}
```

Any ideas how I can bypass the serverless webpack error? Or is there any better way to evaluate a string altogether?

Comment: But why do you need this?